# Can you add a CustomVIew to a ListView without any ArrayAdapters?

Tags: android, listview, android-custom-view

Is there a way to add a custom view with an edittext and a button without any adapters because I dont have any arrays I just need a custom view in each listview . Something like listitem.add(custom view) and i can tell how many times in a for loop. And where do i programme the button in the custom view?

Comment: There should be an addView method, but it isn't clear what you have against using an Adapter

Comment: I dont have an array so I dont get why would I need an adapter?

Comment: Are you sure you need a `ListView` at all? What about a `ScrollView` instead?

Comment: I dont have any data to put in the list exept the custom view , so maybe I do if I can just add the custom view with some add method.

Comment: You don't have to use a ListView. If you just want to manually add views to it, try a LinearLayout instead.