# How do I generate 15 ListItems with CustomViews without an array in the first place

Tags: android

I ve made the adapter but I only need 15 places in the list and I dont have an array to put to int resource, what do I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you add a CustomVIew to a ListView without any ArrayAdapters?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37228690/can-you-add-a-customview-to-a-listview-without-any-arrayadapters)

Comment: Please edit your other question with new information. Maybe add some code with what you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say that you want a custom list view that looks like this :

**list_look.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/1st_text"
        style="@style/liststyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:gravity="center"
       />


</LinearLayout>
```

now you want to fill a ListView in your main.xml that has the list_view id.
the information of your lists is in an ArrayList called data
this will be your adapter:

**MyAdapter**

```
public class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    private ArrayList<String> data;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> values) 
    {
        super(context, R.layout.list_look,values);
        this.data = values;
    }


    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(getContext());
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_look, parent, false);

        String s = data.get(position);

        TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.1st_text);
        text.setText(s);


        return view;
    }
```

now use this adapter in your mainActivity like this :

**MainActivity.onCreate()**

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ArrayList<String> data = getYourOwnDataArray();
        ListView list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.main_list);
        MyAdapter ma = new MyAdapter(this, data);
        list.setAdapter(ma);
    }
```

and thats it, you can adapt a custom data array that you don't have a resource xml file for it in your ListView
I hope it helps :)